# scanf calling malloc without free

Tags: c, malloc, scanf

I was trying to replace the standard library functions `malloc` and `free` with my own versions to detect memory leak. I did this through dynamic linking:

```c
// malloc.c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef __GLIBC__
#error glibc must be used.
#endif

extern void *__libc_malloc(size_t size);
extern void *__libc_free(void *ptr);

void *malloc(size_t size) {
  const char msg[] = "malloc called.\n";
  void *ptr = __libc_malloc(size);
  if (ptr != NULL)
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg) - 1);
  return ptr;
}

void free(void *ptr) {
  const char msg[] = "free called.\n";
  if (ptr != NULL)
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg) - 1);
  __libc_free(ptr);
}
```

Compiled with

```
gcc -shared malloc.c -o libmalloc.so -fpic
```

Then I wrote another C program:

```c
// hello.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_less(const void *a_, const void *b_) {
  const int a = *(const int *)a_, b = *(const int *)b_;
  return a < b ? -1 : (a == b ? 0 : 1);
}

int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
  for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    scanf("%d", a + i);
  }
  qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), &compare_less);
  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    printf("%d, ", a[i]);
  printf("%d\n", a[n - 1]);
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

and link them by

```
gcc hello.c -o hello -L. -lmalloc
```

When I run `./hello`, I found that `malloc called.` was printed three times: during the first call to `scanf`, during the direct call to `malloc`, and during the second call to `scanf`. However `free called.` was only printed once.

I added a breakpoint at `malloc` and GDB backtrace shows the following:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  malloc (size=1024) at malloc.c:12
#1  0x00007ffff7df2c24 in __GI__IO_file_doallocate (fp=0x7ffff7f8daa0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>) at ./libio/filedoalloc.c:101
#2  0x00007ffff7e01d60 in __GI__IO_doallocbuf (fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7f8daa0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>) at ./libio/libioP.h:947
#3  0x00007ffff7e00d5c in _IO_new_file_underflow (fp=0x7ffff7f8daa0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>) at ./libio/fileops.c:485
#4  0x00007ffff7e01e16 in __GI__IO_default_uflow (fp=0x7ffff7f8daa0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>) at ./libio/libioP.h:947
#5  0x00007ffff7dd7150 in __vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdfb0, mode_flags=mode_flags@entry=2)
    at ./stdio-common/vfscanf-internal.c:628
#6  0x00007ffff7dd61c2 in __isoc99_scanf (format=<optimized out>) at ./stdio-common/isoc99_scanf.c:30
#7  0x000055555555525e in main () at hello.c:11
```

It seems that `scanf` calls `malloc` to allocate memory for its buffer, but I did not see `scanf` calling `free`. However, `valgrind` shows that all heap blocks were freed, so that memory must have been freed somehow.

My questions:

1. How is the memory allocated by `scanf` deallocated?
2. If I want to record the calls to `malloc` and `free` from users' code only (i.e. ignoring those from standard libraries like `scanf`), what should I do?

Comment: I suspect memory is free'd via some other function (or `realloc()` - not known to users.  Or maybe its done on program conclusion.  How the C library does  it functionality does not have to be through C code.

Comment: If you can control the code from the user code base you could just write a wrapper around malloc/free

Comment: Generally, when standard library functions call other standard library functions, they do so through an internal name rather than the public name. This allows users to define their own functions with the same names, without breaking the internal callers.

Comment: Re "*to detect memory leak*", fyi, `-fsanitize=address`, or `valgrind`

Comment: Or use `valgrind`.

Comment: valgrind should suppress this warning as it (scanf allocation) is on the list of such unavoidable memory leaks and the output should be suppressed I do not know why this one was outputted.

Comment: @GKxx, Consider outputting through `stderr`.

Comment: @Barmar *Generally, when standard library functions call other standard library functions, they do so through an internal name ...*  `malloc()` *et al* tend to be a bit different so that another library can interpose and take over heap management - like Valgrind does.  These two blocks of memory may be `free()`'d late in process exit, or glibc just might let them leak as they're potentially needed until the process does actually exit, or as mentioned in the first comment cleaned up in other ways. It's a glibc issue either way, and I'd personally just ignore it.